# Updating MasterDetailPage's Header on Android using Prism for Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, navigation, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a MasterDetailPage (called RootPage) and ContentPage (called MainPage).ContentPage's Title property is set to 'This is main page' and I am navigating using NavigationService with the following code:

```
await navigationService.NavigateAsync("RootPage/MainPage");
```

What I expect to see is ContentPage's Title in the MasterDetail's header, but it says 'MainActivity' everytime.

Is this some kind of a platform behavior? If not, how do I set the MasterDetailPage's header to a specific object?

Answer (score 0):

In our app the title of the pages is set correctly in the 'header' of the MasterDetail. Upon starting we navigate like this:

`NavigationService.Navigate("RootPage/DetailsNavigationPage/MainPage")`

When navigating modeless further down, the new pages are also loaded in the 'details' of the MasterDetail and their title is displayed:

`NavigationService.Navigate("AnotherPage", null, false);`

The DetailsNavigation page is a simple page that looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                x:Class="SomeNameSpage.Views.DetailsNavigationPage"
                BarBackgroundColor="Accent">
</NavigationPage>`

And the MasterDetail looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="SomeNameSpace.Views.RootPage">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Default"><!--Must have a Title, otherwise crashes according to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/-->
      <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Main Page" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="DetailsNavigation/MainPage" />
        <Button Text="Some Page" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="DetailsNavigation/SomePage" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>`